After upgrading project to gradle 8.7 circular dependency between tasks appeared because of using sourceSets.main.java.classesDirectory
It is quite old project and everything worked fine with gradle 5.3, then 7.6.3. Now it is attempt to use gradle 8.7 and after small migration changes there is a problem like:
Circular dependency between the following tasks:
:compileJava
--- :schema
--- :compileJava (*)
build.gradle:
sourceSets {
    main {
        resources {
            srcDirs = ["src/main/resources/${RES_DIR}", "..."]
        }

        java {
            srcDirs = ["src/main/java", "src/main/grpc"]
        }
    }
}


tasks.register('schema', JavaExec) {}

[schema ...].each {task ->

    task.classpath = files(sourceSets.main.compileClasspath, sourceSets.main.java.classesDirectory)
    task.mainClass = 'ch.borm.live.init.SchemaGenerator'

    task.dependsOn compileSchema
}



compileJava {
    dependsOn schema
    dependsOn ...
}

Task schema generates java files based on the DB tables. This java files are necessary for compileJava task. Without sourceSets.main.java.classesDirectory there is no circular dependency, but error "Could not find or load main class ch.borm.live.init.SchemaGenerator".
And yes, it looks like logically that I got this circular dependency, because I try to use compiled classes from classesDirectory, but how it worked earlier?
Main goal is to migrate to gradle 8.7

Does this answer your question? Circular dependency between the following tasks in gradle

No, it is not related to my case.

Are you after suggestions for how to fix the problem, or just reasons why it used to work? For the latter, I do not know: it looks from your code like the circular dependency would already have been there as there is a clear circular dependency chain there. Gradle 8 did make some changes to what dependency relationships were an error though (eg non-declared implicit dependencies became an error docs) but that doesn't seem to be quite it

Now I am looking for the solution - how to use gradle 8.7 and fix this circular dependency
